# TextViews appear on top of each other

Tags: android, android-layout

Im creating an app that requires three headings at the top of the activity. When trying to put them there, they do not appear beside eachother along the top, but beneath each other in a line. 
This is my xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Starters"
    android:id="@+id/tvStarter"
    android:layout_gravity="left" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Main Course"
    android:id="@+id/tvMain"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Desserts"
    android:id="@+id/tvDessert"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

Comment: is this your complete xml? can you post the complete xml?

Comment: what is the type of the parent layout

Comment: If you are using the Design Tab, it is much easier to align your Views. Either that, or you just aren't using a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the orientation of the parent view:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- your TextViews -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, so the orientation should be "horizontal"

Answer (score 0):

This would be helpfull:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Starters"
    android:id="@+id/tvStarter"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Main Course"
    android:id="@+id/tvMain" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Desserts"
    android:id="@+id/tvDessert" />

</LinearLayout>
```